# HTML: Two column layer, one column with auto height and the other with auto width

Tags: html, css

I've been out of the HTML/CSS game for a while and it seems like I'm a bit rusty.  I'm looking to make a simple two column layout (for just a part of my page, there will be more underneath).  Column A will have a fixed width and it's height will be determined by it's content (maybe have a max-height, and scroll after that).  The problem that's really getting to me is getting Column B's height to match Column A.  Additionally, this column is to expand to fill the remainder of the width of the view area.  Any ideas?

```
+-------------+------------------------------------+
|  Column A   |              Column B              |
|             |                                    |
| Fixed Width |   Expands L to R to fill window    |
|             |                                    |
| Height auto |   Height inherited from column A   |
| to fit the  |                                    |
| content of  |                                    |
| column      |                                    |
+-------------+------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="aside">
        <p>Column A</p>
        <p>Column A</p>
        <p>Column A</p>
        <p>Column A</p>
        <p>Column A</p>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <p>Column B</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.aside {
  float: left;
  overflow-y:auto;
  width: 100px;
  max-height: 200px;
  background: #ddd;
}
.main {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-bottom: 99999px;
  margin-bottom: -99999px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/akai/NHghW/

Answer (score 0):

Html Code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">left</div>
    <div class="right">right</div>
    <div class="clear" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container
{
    width:100%;
}
.left
{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    background-color: blue;

}
.right
{
    background-color: green;
    margin-left:200px;
}
.clear
{
    clear:both;
}
```

To See it in action http://jsfiddle.net/BTaMx/

Comment: Your demo does not work, as the left column does not match the right columns height when adding more content. http://jsfiddle.net/BTaMx/1/

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the columns don't appear to be of equal height (on Chrome 14, at least)  http://jsfiddle.net/BTaMx/2/

Answer (score 0):

The CSS 3 way is to use `display: box`

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;

    width: 100%;
}

.left {
    width: 100px;
}

.right {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    box-flex: 1;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/AEY7p/ for a demo

Comment: Looks great, thanks!  I need to do a bit of reading on CSS3 and HTML5, obviously.  Do you know how widely supported this is?

Comment: Furthermore, is it possible to make it so that Column A does NOT have it's height inherited from Column B (imagine that Column B has more content in it than Column A, ideally Column B would be restricted to the height of column A)

Comment: IE7/8 does not play with CSS3. -1